# Python - Running many different types of threads without exhausting resources

Tags: threadpool, python-3.5, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I am attempting to do some clean multi-threading but maybe my approach is wrong.

I have a `BaseFix` Thread class with 6 different types of children, one of which is `CommandFix` Thread, another is `ParamFix` Thread.

Their `run` functions have different code inside them, but will mostly utilize the `subprocess.run` function.

```
class CommandFix(BaseFix):

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
             args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None):

        super(CommandFix, self).__init__(group=group, target=target, 
                      name=name, kwargs=kwargs, verbose=None)


    def _execute_command(self):
        self.stdout_log.write("fixing {} : running command {}".format(
            self.rule_id,
            self.command))

        try:
            cp = subprocess.run(self.command,
                shell=True, check=True,
                stdout=self.stdout_log,
                stderr=self.stderr_log
                )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            self.stderr_log.write("error fixing {} : {}".format(
                self.rule_id,
                e))

            # TO-DO: Handle error with retry or similar
            # right now just return false
            return False

        return True

    def _verify_command(self):
        pass

    def run(self):

        # execute the command
        if self._execute_command():
            # now run the verification
            pass
        else:
            # TO-DO: error handling
            pass
```

I have about `200` fixes of about `6` different types.  I am checking their fix type, then instantiating the required Fix and calling `run` like so:

```
def _fix(key, rule):
    expr = "./{}fixtext".format(NS)
    fixtext = rule.find(expr)

    expr = "./{}div".format(NS1)
    fixtext = fixtext.find(expr).getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].text

    if fixtext.find('Run the following command') > 0:
        fix = CommandFix(rule, stdout_log, stderr_log, key)

    elif fixtext.find('Set the following') > 0:
        # fix = SomeOtherFix()
        pass

    elif fixtext.find('For 32 bit systems') > 0:
        # fix = SomeOtherKindOfFix()
        pass

    fix.run()

# there are only 200 but assume there are 2 million
for key, rule in rules.items():
    _fix(key, rule)
```

What I would like to do is clean this up so that I am only executing `X number of fixes` at one time so that I don't exhaust the system's resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already said in the tags of your question: use a pool. As long as your `*Fix()`s invoke `subprocess.run()`, they spawn new processes for real parallelism anyway. Hence, a thread pool is enough:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool    # wrapper around the threading module
#from multiprocessing import Pool         # real processes instead of threads
[...]
pool = Pool(5)                            # number of fixes at once
pool.starmap(_fix, rules.items())
```